# How to check "Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives" status?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

What Woocommerce function check status of this checkbox "Enable AJAX add to cart buttons on archives"? I need to execute my code in different ways if it is checked or not, so need to check it's status first with some function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the status of that option via `get_option('woocommerce_enable_ajax_add_to_cart')`. Which will return `yes` when the option is checked, and `no` if it is not.

Comment: Exactly what i need! Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Glad this answer was useful for you.